# How I can calculate this limit about the sequence of primes?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

Let $\left\{\, p_{n}\,\right\}$ be the sequence of consecutive primes.
$$\mbox{How I can calculate}\quad
\lim_{n\ \to\ \infty}{\left(\,  -p_{n}^2+2p_{n}+2p_{n+1}+2p_{n}p_{n+1}-1\,\right)\over
                       \left(\, 2p_{n+1}^2+2p_{n}-p_{n}^2+2p_{n+1}+2p_{n}p_{n+1}- 1\,\right)}\ {\large ?}
$$

I've tried to use the fact that
$\displaystyle{\lim_{n\ \to\ \infty}p_{n} = +\infty}$ but I cannot arrive at any result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Divide numerator and denominator by $p_n^2$, and use the fact that $p_{n+1}/p_n \to 1$ while $p_n \to \infty$ and $p_{n+1} \to \infty$.

Comment: I'm a little confused. would you please explain why $p_{n+1}/p_n\to 1$?

Comment: HINT. $$p_n \sim n\ln(n),$$
Ssee [Prime number theorem] (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem).